# Multiple が in sentence with adjective

Tags: grammar, particle-が

Is it natural to use multiple が in one sentence like this one below?

> 日本人は私の友だちが背が高いことに驚きました。

Is it correct and more natural to rephrase it like this?

> 日本人は私の友だちの背が高いことに驚きました。

Answer (score 1):

Some may say it's a poor writing style to repeat -が in succession. That doesn't make it unnatural, however, especially in speech.